# Jailbroken iPhone 5s stuck in boot loop and can't be seen by iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, jailbreak, iphone

I got my iPhone stolen and I'm guessing he tried to do a factory reset, but I know jailbreak does something differently with that but it's stuck in a bootloop and I've tried just about everything I can do with iTunes and putting the phone in different modes.

Power + home for 10 sec then just home = Apple update logo then crashes and goes back to boot loop.

Power and + volume = nothing

The computer can't recognize the device, it did once but I don't know what I did but it stopped and went back to unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter DFU mode during a bootloop:

1. Connect the device to the computer and open iTunes. It won't be detected—that's fine.
2. Hold down the power and home buttons together.
3. The display will turn off, then an Apple logo is shown. Keep holding until the display turns off for a second time.
4. As soon as the display turns off the second time, keep holding home but release the power button.
5. The display will remain blank and iTunes will prompt you to restore the device. Now release the home button.